Generate the set of vectors with entries in a non-unital ring in MAGMA
I have the non-unital ring $R := u \mathbb{F}_2 + v \mathbb{F}_2 = \{ 0 , u , v , u + v  \}$ that satisfies $u^2 = v^2 = uv = vu = 0$. How do I get the set of all $n$-tuples (where $n$ is arbitrary and can be changed) with entries in $R$ using MAGMA?
By doing a search, I came to this link and found out the code RMatrixSpace(R, m, n) but I cannot use it requires the ring to be unital.
Is there a workaround for this one?
Thank you in advance for any help.

I don't see why you wouldn't just work over the unital ring (by including 1 so you will have 8 total elements) in this case, and then just getting rid of the vectors you don't want. (Also you should use RSpace and not RMatrixSpace is you want vectors and not matrices.)
